# Post tweet in twitter directly from my website using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

My website is allow user to tweet something to their timeline in twitter. When they click on tweet button, twitter box platform will popup and user can write or edit something before tweet; but I don't want this way, I want is when they click on tweet button it will tweet to their timeline automatically (no need to call twitter box platform). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the twitter's documentation :
https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

When using the Twitter API, anything that you want to do that involves a user's account (post tweets, retweet, favorite, etc. ) will require permission from the user. This permission is given in the form of a user's unique access key and secret.

In order to obtain a user's key & secret you will need to authenticate the user using a Twitter sign in. This process **will** take the user to Twitter's sign in page. Once they have successfully signed in they will be redirected back to your app.

For further reading, please see: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

```
const windowReference=window.location.href;
const hrefEl="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + windowReference + "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(textToTweet);
tweetButton.setAttribute('href',hrefEl)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?